# Defining and populating TableCells with Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sharepoint

I'm trying to define a TableCell Array, but are having some problems.
My code is as follows

```
public partial class ShowGoalsUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPWeb _web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPList objGoalsList = _web.Lists["Goals"];

        SPListItemCollection goalsItems = getItemsByQueryID(objGoalsList);

        foreach (SPItem goalItem in goalsItems)
        {
            goalTitle.Text = "<h3>" + Convert.ToString(goalItem["Title"]) + "</h3>";
            txtDescription.Text = Convert.ToString(goalItem["Description"]);

            TableCell[] tc = new TableCell[9];

            for (int i = 0; i < tc.Length; i++)
            {
                tc[i] = new TableCell();
            }

            tc[0].Text = "Status:";
            setStatus(goalItem, tc[1], _web);

            tc[2].Text = "Owner:";
            SPFieldLookupValue thisOwner = getOwner(goalItem);
            tc[3].Text = thisOwner.LookupValue;

            tc[4].Text = "Perspective:";
            SPFieldLookupValue thisPerspective = new SPFieldLookupValue(goalItem["Perspective"].ToString());
            tc[5].Text = thisPerspective.LookupValue;

            tc[6].Text = "Parent:";
            SPFieldLookupValue thisParent = new SPFieldLookupValue(goalItem["Parent"].ToString());
            tc[7].Text = thisParent.LookupValue;

            tc[8].Text = "Deadline:";
            tc[9].Text = Convert.ToString(goalItem["Deadline"]);

            TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[4];

            for (int p = 0; p < tr.Length; p++)
            {
                tr[p] = new TableRow();
            }

            setTableRow(tc[0], tc[1], tr[0]);
            setTableRow(tc[2], tc[3], tr[1]);
            setTableRow(tc[4], tc[5], tr[2]);
            setTableRow(tc[6], tc[7], tr[3]);
            setTableRow(tc[8], tc[9], tr[4]);

            addToTable(tr);

        }
    }

    SPListItemCollection getItemsByQueryID(SPList list)
    {
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + Request.QueryString["gid"] + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
        return items;
    }

    void setStatus(SPItem item, TableCell status, SPWeb web)
    {
        string statusTest = Convert.ToString(item["Status"]);

        switch (statusTest)
        {
            case "Approved":
                status.Text = "<img src='" + web.Site.Url + "/_layouts/images/kpidefaultlarge-0.gif' height='10' width='10' />";
                break;

            case "Pending":
                status.Text = "<img src='" + web.Site.Url + "/_layouts/images/kpidefaultlarge-1.gif' height='10' width='10' />";
                break;

            case "Declined":
                status.Text = "<img src='" + web.Site.Url + "/_layouts/images/kpidefaultlarge-2.gif' height='10' width='10' />";
                break;
        }
    }

    SPFieldLookupValue getOwner(SPItem item)
    {
        SPFieldLookupValue getThisOwner = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["Owner"].ToString());
        return getThisOwner;
    }

    void setTableRow(TableCell add1, TableCell add2, TableRow row)
    {
        row.Cells.Add(add1);
        row.Cells.Add(add2);
    }

    void addToTable(TableRow[] tableRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableRow.Length; i++)
        {
            infoTable.Rows.Add(tableRow[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

When I try to run this on the site I get the following error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index
>   was outside the bounds of the array.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any better way to do it? 
Any comments would be helpful!

**EDIT: tc[3] changed to tc[2]**
**EDIT2: Posted full code**

Comment: The conditions should be either `i < tc.Length` or `i <= tc.Length - 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your for loop doesn't make sense. With an array of three elements, it runs only two times. Because of this, the third element in your array (`tc[2]`) is `null`, because it never gets a value assigned to it. The same goes for your second loop.

Use this instead:

```
for (int p = 0; p < tc.Length; p++)
```

BTW: The last line of your example will throw an exception:

```
setTableRow(tc[2], tc[3], tr[1]);
```

`tc[3]` is the fourth element in an array of three items. This will result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

**UPDATE:**
After you posted your full code, I can say this:

The following lines cause a `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

```
tc[9].Text = Convert.ToString(goalItem["Deadline"]);

setTableRow(tc[8], tc[9], tr[4]);
```

You created an array with 9 elements, i.e. with indexes 0 through **8**. `tc[9]` tries to access the 10th element in an array of 9! To fix that problem, increase the size of your array to 10:

```
TableCell[] tc = new TableCell[10];
```

Additionally, you have the same problem with your `TableRow` array, so you should increase its size, too:

```
TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[5];
```

Comment: That was my original loop, however, I get the error message: Index was outside the bounds of the array, whenever I use it.

Comment: That's not possible with the code you posted. In this case, your real code and the code you posted are not matching...

Comment: I have posted the full code now, still get the index out of bounds error. Can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course :) Changed the elements and it works perfectly :) Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but when you create array:

```
TableCell[] tc = new TableCell[3]
```

you have elements:

```
tc[0], tc[1], tc[2]
```

You cannot assign to tc[3].
Also, why you make a loops with Length - 1 ? Should be to full Length;

Comment: This was just a typo, it should say tc[2], not tc[3]. Also, i put -1 in the loop because i got an Index was outside the bounds of the array error message :)